# Padding issue inside cards with bootstrap row class

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, bootstrap-5

[Image of what its looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egY5g.png)

## Can anyone help me this layout issue. when i put the row class in **featured__cars** div its gives this layout issue.

PS: I am only using bootstrap flex utilities and grid system

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="featured__cards row my-5 px-5 px-md-0">
        <div class="featured__card col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
          <img
            class="img-fluid"
            src="./assets/images/Rectangle 69.png"
            alt=""
          />
          <div class="px-3 pb-4">
            <div
              class="card--title d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"
            >
              <h4 class="my-3">Ford Raptor</h4>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-heart me-1"></i>
                <p>5</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="featured__types d-flex align-items-center px-2">
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car-passengers.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">5</p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car-door.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">4</p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car-engine.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">5.0L</p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">Sedan</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="mt-4" />
            <div
              class="featured__price d-flex align-items-end justify-content-between mt-3"
            >
              <div>
                <p>Price</p>
                <p><span>$</span>162000</p>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-secondary">Buy Now</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="featured__card col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
          <img
            class="img-fluid"
            src="./assets/images/Rectangle 69.png"
            alt=""
          />
          <div class="px-3 pb-4">
            <div
              class="card--title d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"
            >
              <h4 class="my-3">Ford Raptor</h4>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-heart me-1"></i>
                <p>5</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="featured__types d-flex align-items-center px-2">
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car-passengers.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">5</p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car-door.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">4</p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car-engine.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">5.0L</p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">Sedan</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="mt-4" />
            <div
              class="featured__price d-flex align-items-end justify-content-between mt-3"
            >
              <div>
                <p>Price</p>
                <p><span>$</span>162000</p>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-secondary">Buy Now</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="featured__card col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
          <img
            class="img-fluid"
            src="./assets/images/Rectangle 69.png"
            alt=""
          />
          <div class="px-3 pb-4">
            <div
              class="card--title d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"
            >
              <h4 class="my-3">Ford Raptor</h4>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-heart me-1"></i>
                <p>5</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="featured__types d-flex align-items-center px-2">
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car-passengers.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">5</p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car-door.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">4</p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car-engine.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">5.0L</p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">Sedan</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="mt-4" />
            <div
              class="featured__price d-flex align-items-end justify-content-between mt-3"
            >
              <div>
                <p>Price</p>
                <p><span>$</span>162000</p>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-secondary">Buy Now</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="featured__card col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
          <img
            class="img-fluid"
            src="./assets/images/Rectangle 69.png"
            alt=""
          />
          <div class="px-3 pb-4">
            <div
              class="card--title d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"
            >
              <h4 class="my-3">Ford Raptor</h4>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-heart me-1"></i>
                <p>5</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="featured__types d-flex align-items-center px-2">
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car-passengers.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">5</p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car-door.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">4</p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car-engine.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">5.0L</p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="./assets/images/icons/car.svg" alt="" />
                <p class="ms-2">Sedan</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="mt-4" />
            <div
              class="featured__price d-flex align-items-end justify-content-between mt-3"
            >
              <div>
                <p>Price</p>
                <p><span>$</span>162000</p>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-secondary">Buy Now</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.featured__card {
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-card);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
}
.featured__img img {
  border-radius: var(--border-img);
}

.card--title h4 {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.featured__types {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  column-gap: 1.75rem;
  row-gap: 0.5rem;
}
.featured__types div img {
  height: 25px;
}
.featured__price div p:nth-child(1),
.card--title div,
.featured__types div {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card--title div i {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.favourite-checked {
  color: var(--favourite-checked);
}

.featured__price div p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.featured__price div p:nth-child(2) span {
  color: var(--primary);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

I want to show this as the card should.. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .. . . . . .. . . . . . . . ....................................... . .
..  ..................................................

Comment: Could you be more specific about what the issue is, what you want to happen. For me, `row` on `featured__cards` does what I'd expect and makes everything be in a single row, which will wrap if there's not enough space.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.